# How to synchronize threads that receive images with url

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, synchronization, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 to Get some string data and image url from the server and recyclerview shows the received data.

I used a thread to get an image with url.

However, since threads are asynchronous, the problem is that the next action is taken while the image is being retrieved by url.

This is the code that I use to retrieve data using retrofit

```
public void getData(ArrayList<String> IdList, int len) {
    Call<RepoReviewData> call = gitHubService.getReviewListData(IdList);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RepoReviewData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RepoReviewData> call, Response<RepoReviewData> response) {
            RepoReviewData repo = response.body();
            String message = repo.getMessage();
            if(message.equals("found")){
                List<RepoReviewData.ReviewList> reviewList = repo.getReviewList();
                reviewDataset.clear();
                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    String Id = reviewList.get(i).getUser_Id();
                    ArrayList<String> image_IDs = reviewList.get(i).getReview_Image_List();
                    task.execute(image_IDs);
                }
                    reviewAdapter.addAll(reviewDataset);
                    reviewAdapter.setProgressMore(true);
                    reviewAdapter.setMoreLoading(true);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RepoReviewData> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

and this is my asynctask code

```
private class back extends AsyncTask<String[], Integer,ArrayList<Bitmap>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(String[]... urls) {
        try{
            images = new ArrayList<>();

            int Alen = urls.length;
            for(int i = 0; i<Alen; i++){
                java.net.URL myFileUrl = new URL(urls[i].toString());
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                images.add(bmImg);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return images;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> img){

    }
}
```

But it runs asynchronously and does not work the way I want.

I know that I need to update recyclerview with the value returned after the asynctask.

But I do not know how to do it.

If you know how to do this or if you know a good example, I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Thank you for reading and hope you have a good day!

Comment: Use **[glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** to load image from url

Comment: You simply put all the code that needs the bitmap in the onPoseExecute.  Then it will only run when you have all the data.  If you want it to run off the UI thread, then put it at the end of doInBackground.

Comment: `task.execute(image_IDs);` What is `task' ? You can call execute() only once on an asynctask instance.

Comment: Fresco is also a good and easy option to go with. Link: http://frescolib.org/

Comment: Thanks to everyone who advised! It was solved using glide.
I wish everyone a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download images and get `Bitmap` using `AsyncTask`

You can simply use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to load images in your `RecyclerView`

In your `onBindViewHolder` holder user below code

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        String url = list.get(position).imageurl;
        Glide.with(context) 
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.piwo_48)
                .transform(new CircleTransform(context)) 
                .into(holder.imageView);

}
```

**Hope this will help**

Comment: I adopted this answer because I solved it using Glide. Thank you very much!